# Business goal coverage

Tags: agile, requirements

Currently we find we have a lot of code that sometimes overlaps an end user feature, in some cases only contributes to a tenth of a feature, or it even looks like shouldn't be there anymore

The codebase is quite big so we don't feel confident enough to rip things out without a solid reason.

Is there a recommended approach that helps identify business goals and how much a framework contributes to such goal?

Comment: I don't think you've thought this out.  Even if code only contributes to a tenth of one feature, it might contribute to half of another.

Comment: Correct, which is why what may seem good to remove today may be a mistake tomorrow. The nature of the question is exactly that, how to properly think this through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not generally possible to reverse-engineer the original requirements from the code. Often, this code has “organically grown” into an incomprehensible mess, or has been copied from other components, without deleting unneeded parts.

There are however a number of techniques that can be helpful to understand the purpose of this code, and decide whether to remove it.

- Investigate the version control history, and compare it with historical records in your bug database. When was this line of code written? Which bugs were being worked on at the time?
- Write test cases for this code. Under what circumstances will this code be exercised? End-to-end tests or integration tests are more useful here, as unit tests might be able to exercise code that's unreachable during normal operation.
- Add logging to these parts, and observe whether they are ever used during real-world usage. The danger is that some use cases may be seasonal, so you might not observe their usage in the chosen observation window. This depends a lot on the nature of your product.
- Perform safe refactoring to remove duplication. With a bit of experience, it is possible to safely extract common code from multiple components, even when there is only partial test coverage. Then, consider which differences remain. Why might these differences be important? Perhaps there's no good reason, and the differences should be corrected.

  Without test coverage this is still a high-risk manoeuvre, so be sure to proceed in small steps, get your work reviewed, and preferably add tests while you're taking the code apart.

At the end, quite a lot of code will usually only be there for various edge cases: features are also a liability. This doesn't mean these edge cases are unimportant. If every user only needs 60% of your features but everyone uses a *different* 60%, then limiting the product to the common subset of features means building a product for no one. So edge cases do have value, but sometimes they are not worth the added maintenance burden.

Comment: Really helps to know there isn't a 'by the book' process. While this is helping with our old code, we found that 'story mapping' is handy moving onwards.